# Should I use a C# Event / Postback, or Javascript for something simple?

Tags: c#, jquery, postback

For the sake of argument, I have a DropDownList, with a variable number of items in. Let's say they come from an ObjectDataSource. I also have a TextBox, which I want to contain that value. Bear with me here.

E.G.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlOptions">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 1" Value="Value1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 2" Value="Value2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 3" Value="Value3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtOptionValue"></asp:TextBox>
```

My question is - should I use a Postback to set the value, or some Javascript? I can either use the SelectedIndexChanged event of the DropDownList, or I can hook it up using some jQuery .change(func...) magic.

I'm not asking **how** to do this, but which would be the **preferred method**? Personally, I think using jQuery looks cleaner to the end-user, but using a postback is more of a 'standard' way of doing things? Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: if you use javascript, you avoid a request to your server.  I'd say, if you don't *need* to make a request, why do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAVASCRIPT is meant to be used whatever you can do on client side.

The thing that you are doing is clearly possible to be done using jQuery so there is no need to hit the server just to set the value.

Try to reduce server hit as many as possible. This should be the motto of developers

Comment: I quite like your last line there, and makes alot of sense. +1, thanks. My original thought is that postback is good for standardising the way your application works, but server resource should clearly come first!

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are right jQuery is the best option, but it's all depends on your requirement, if the 
page is not having any post backs then you can chose JQuery otherwise better to chose postback..

Comment: The snippet I posted is _part_ of the page. There's a lot more to it. I think I'm going with Javascript as much as possible, with a postback at the end to "save" the page, and continue - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably think about the overall architecture and user experience requirements.

Lets say your clients want a smooth experience, something like a single page app. Then yes, start throwing in all the javascript and jquery you can to achieve as this, with something like WebAPI instead of asp.net. Check out [ASP.NET SPA](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application).

Lets say your client isn't requiring anything fancy. Why go through all the trouble of adding javascript when you can quickly achieve it by using standard asp.net callbacks.

It looks like you are using ASP.net. I would stick with normal out-of-the-box asp.net unless the requirements say otherwise. No sense in throwing in all these other libraries or dependencies if if this is the only place you'll use it.

Comment: The snippet is part of one page in a complex multi-part form. This particular page _does_ use jQueryUI (datepickers, etc), so it references the jQuery library anyway. My thoughts on using a Postback is for standardisation throughout the app (as it does use Postbacks in some places), but, as Patel said, the server hit is unnecessary. That siad, WebAPI looks interesting, and something I'll certainly look at for smaller projects -- thanks!